# Use node.js without access to a command prompt

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd

I'm trying to use Node.js in my school environment which blocks all use of cmd.exe on Windows, therefore I'm not able to use Node this way.

Is there any other way to use it, or an alternative (external) command prompt application I could use?

Comment: if you double-click node.exe, does it work? It should launch the REPL without starting cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

If the com.exe access is blocked in local OS, it is suggested to use virtual machine to help developing you project. Please have a look on [how to use virtual machine](https://www.howtogeek.com/196060/beginner-geek-how-to-create-and-use-virtual-machines/). [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) would be a nice try.

After building a virtual machine on your Windows host, you can do most of the development stuffs there(including use Node.js from [cli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)). Hope that helps!

Comment: VM actually sounds like a pretty good idea, though do you know if I could use it from an USB drive, since I dont't have enough personal space on the school computers to install a VM.

Comment: @jdK For what I thought, if the personal space is limited, it might be hard for you to develop a Node.js project that depends on some external modules(Libraries and APIs), yet most Node.js projects do. Please consider developing it on the other devices with enough space and sufficient access.

Comment: then, I'm still wondering if I could use, for example a large USB drive and install a VM there?

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud 9](https://c9.io/) is an online cloud-based editor. You can set a Node.js environment up there and execute app code that way. Otherwise, I'd suggest using a virtual machine or a Docker image.